# Dart Substring End Index error when longer than string parameter

Tags: flutter, dart

In Dart substring doesn't like it if the end index exceeds the string length. Do I really have to do some If precheck to make sure that 2nd parameter is adjusted to avoid this?   In other languages like python this is far more organic on achieving this, and many substring functions in other language assume you want the full length if it end index is longer...

The idea is to use a standard function that receives a string of varying length substring only the first X characters.  Of course the original string may be much shorter or longer than the substring end index i want.

Comment: I think there is no standard way that is built within `dart` to handle this issue. That being said you can always write a custom function(say `safeSubstr`) to serve your purpose

Answer (score 0):

The [`String.substring` documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/String/substring.html) is pretty umambiguous:

> Both `start` and `end` must be non-negative and no greater than `length`; `end`, if provided, must be greater than or equal to `start`.

So, no, there's no built-in way to relax `String.substring`'s restrictions.  You can always create your own extension method:

```dart
import 'dart:math';

extension LooseSubstring on String {
  /// Returns a substring from `start` (inclusive) to `end` (exclusive).
  ///
  /// Unlike [String.substring], clamps `start` and `end` to [length].  Thus
  /// if `start` is out-of-bounds, returns an empty string.  If `end` is
  /// out-of-bounds, returns the substring from `start` to the end of this
  /// string.
  ///
  /// If `start` >= `end`, returns an empty string.
  String substringLoose(int start, [int? end]) {
    start = min(length, start);
    end = max(start, min(length, end ?? length));
    return substring(start, end);
  }
}
```